# elasticsearch default_field vs fields different results

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is two queries.
First:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "27444.2",
          "default_field": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

Second:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "27444.2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": ["text"],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

The only difference between them is that in first i use default_field to specify a field to search, and in second i specify  it through fields param. The field name is the same.
I expect both variant to produce same results, but thats not the case. The first variant doesn't return any results, and the second return a result. So what im doing wrong here? Where is the catch

elasticsearch 1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have given fields param is wrong.
In the second case you are referring to the [field params in the query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) where you are restricting the results to show only certain fields and not the entire _source

The following one is what you are looking for -

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "27444.2",
          "fields": ["text"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2 queries are not the same.
First searches the field 'text' and second searches all fields and in response, returns only 'field'.